# set parameters via addwithvalue to stored procedure using odbc

Tags: vb.net, odbc

I use codes below to inserts values to database by executing stored procedure.

```
 Dim connstring As String = "dsn=test"
 Dim oConn As Odbc.OdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(connstring)
 Dim com As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("{? = call sp_test1(?,?,?,?)}", oConn)
 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", 2)
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "2")
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Familly", "2")
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pname", "2")
 oConn.Open()
 com.ExecuteNonQuery()
 oConn.Close()
```

but I got this error

```
ERROR [HY105] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter type
```

and here is my stored procedure

```
USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create Procedure [dbo].[sp_test1]
 @Code bigint,
 @Name nvarchar(50),
 @Familly nvarchar(50),
 @Pname nvarchar(50),
    As
    Begin
 Insert Into test1
  ([Code],[Name],[Familly],[Pname])
 Values
  (@Code,@Name,@Familly,@Pname)

 Declare @ReferenceID int
 Select @ReferenceID = @@IDENTITY

 Return @ReferenceID

 End
```

is there a  solution ?

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance, the stored procedure has the 1st parameter of type `bigint` whereas it is given a string value in form of an input.

`com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", "2")`

Change the above to

`com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", 2)`

Does that work?

EDIT: Can you change this line

`Dim com As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("{? = call sp_test1(?,?,?,?)}", oConn)`

to

`Dim com As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("sp_test1", oConn)`

Comment: in add with value I think it doesent matter if I use "2" or 2. the value is important to be number.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because you have not passed the Return Value parameter, which is specified in CommandText, but is missing from parameters collection (the first question mark in the command text IS the return value parameter).

Because parameters must be passed sequentially, ODBC considers, that @Code is the RETURN_VALUE, and @Name is actually @Code, so the type mismatch error occurs.

You must add the following code

```
com.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", 2)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "2")
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Familly", "2")
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pname", "2")
```